# Is the Lie algebra of any one-parameter group the same [X,X] = 0?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've started to study Lie groups recently and one thing seems confusing to me. If we have a 1-parameter group, what will be its Lie algebra?

As far as I understood, the number of generators of the group is the number of parameters, so 1-parameter group has only one generator *X*. So, I guess, the algebra of one generator will be $[X, X] = 0$ ? The idea of this seems a little confusing, because it's just trivial. Am I mistaken in some point?

Comment: Yes, any $1$-dimensional Lie algebra has basis a single element, hence antisymmetry forces the bracket to be trivial.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you!

Comment: It is useful to remember that the Lie algebra of a Lie group is it's tangent space in the identity